# RecyclerView state restored not showing items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, restore

I'm having two fragments which are displayed one at a time and I toggle them with the following method:

```
public void toggle() {
  Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
  if (fragment instanceof OtherFragment && null != listFragment) {
      // Other frag is visible - we should show the list now

      // We reuse the fragment if it was already added to the manager
      fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_LIST);
      if (fragment == null) {
          fragment = listFragment;
      }
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                 .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in,
                                                      R.anim.fade_out)
                                 .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG_LIST)
                                 .addToBackStack(TAG_LIST)
                                 .commit();
  } else if (fragment instanceof ListFragment && null != otherFragment) {
      // List is visible - we show show the other fragment now

      // We reuse the fragment if it was already added to the manager
      fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_OTHER);
      if (fragment == null) {
          fragment = otherFragment;
      }
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                 .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in,
                                                      R.anim.fade_out)
                                 .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG_OTHER)
                                 .addToBackStack(TAG_OTHER)
                                 .commit();
  } else {
      getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
}
```

In my list fragment, in the onCreateView() I verify if the recyclerView instance is still valid (I have an global field for that):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    if (null != mRecyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView.invalidate();
        // Skip the initialization process
        return;
    } else {
        // init recycler view
    }

    return view;
}
```

The issue I have encountered is that when I change from the other fragment to the list fragment, the views for the adapter data are not created anymore. `onBindViewHolder` and `onCreateViewHolder` are never called.

I have checked and `getItemCount()` returns an valid value.
I have also made sure the `recyclerView` is visible. 
The `recyclerView` seems to have the exact state as when he was displayed.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Does anyone have an solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest adding the second fragment using `.add` instead of `.replace` and removing the second fragment using `.remove` in case you want to toggle back.

This will help retaining the state of fragment 1 and will recreate view for fragment 2.

Edit #1

Try putting the setting of data in adapter and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after a delay of 1sec inside if statement of onCreateView().

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                \\ set adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() here.
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: The issue is not the state of the fragment, but of the recyclerView and/or adapter.
The fragment has it's state restored correctly, as I have mentioned, the recyclerView has kept it's original values.
Also, the add method won't change anything(documentation for replace() method: "Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.")

Comment: So is the problem that the data in the recycler view is not getting updated?

Comment: Yes, When I'm changing back to the list fragment, the rows aren't displayed anymore. The `onBindViewHolder()` is never called.

If I leave the initialization of the recyclerView for restore state also, the data is displayed (a new adapter is created), but I get an flickering effect which I wan't to avoid.

Comment: Did you try setting the data in adapter again and calling notifyDataSetChanged after restoring state.

Comment: Yes, but the result seems to be the same.

Comment: Try creating a new Adapter and setting that to the recyclerView. Does it flicker in this case too?

Comment: Yes, that was the old flow I was using. In onCreateView() of the fragment I was doing the intialization for the recyclerview & adapter from scratch, no matter the flow.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue when coming back to previous fragment. My spinner would not show any data. I used the following workaround for it. Set the data to adapter again and call the notifyDataSetChanged after delay of 1 second. Posting the code snippet as updated answer. Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: If you create and set a new adapter you shouldn't be required to call notify afterwards, this is what I'm doing now, but all my data is recreated, thus creating an flashing effect (the entire flow is started from scratch, with my requests and everything).

I've debugged the flow a little more, and I suspect the reason for this is because I inflate a new layout, with new data. I'll have to figure out a way to restore the entire layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this issue after some intensive debugging.
It seems that the `RecyclerView` has some restore options, but only regarding it's layout manager.

I have fixed this Issue, by using an global variable for the `RecyclerView` and in `onCreateView()` I reuse the adapter that was set on it if any:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

// Try to reuse the old adapter, if any set on the recyclerView
MyAdapter mAdapter = null != mRecyclerView ? (MyAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter() : null;

mRecyclerView = findById(rootView, android.R.id.list);

// Setup the recycler view everytime
...

// If no adapter to reuse, just create a new one
if (null == mAdapter) {
  // create a new adapter again
  ...
}

// Bind the adapter to the RecyclerView
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```